# Adding Operation Behaviors with WCF Facility

Tags: wcf, castle-windsor, wcffacility

I'm using the WCF Facility for the first time to host a couple 
services, both in a console app (for easy debugging) and IIS (for 
production). The services use a **net.msmq** endpoint.

This is how I'm hosting the service in the console app (simplified):

```
using (var host = new DefaultServiceHostFactory() 
                    .CreateServiceHost(typeof(MyService).AssemblyQualifiedName, 
                                       new Uri[0])) 
    host.Open();
```

And here's how it's registered:

```
container.Register(Component.For<UserRequestService>()
                            .LifestylePerWcfOperation())
```

What I'd like to do is to add the following behavior to all operations:

```
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true,
                   TransactionAutoComplete = true)]
```

Here's what I tried:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IOperationBehavior>() 
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(
                                x => new OperationBehaviorAttribute 
                                { 
                                    TransactionScopeRequired = true, 
                                    TransactionAutoComplete = true 
                                }));
```

But that results in an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'System.ServiceModel.OperationBehaviorAttribute'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.
Parameter name: item
   at System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32 index, TItem item)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.Internal.WcfUtils.AddBehaviors[T](IKernel kernel, WcfExtensionScope scope, KeyedByTypeCollection`1 behaviors, IWcfBurden burden, Predicate`1 predicate)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfEndpointExtensions.Install(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, Boolean withContract, IKernel kernel, IWcfBurden burden)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.ServiceHostExtensions.Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.IWcfExtensionVisitor.VisitEndpointExtension(IWcfEndpointExtension extension)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.ServiceHostExtensions.Install(ICollection`1 extensions, IWcfBurden burden)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.AbstractServiceHostBuilder.ConfigureServiceHost(ServiceHost serviceHost, IWcfServiceModel serviceModel, ComponentModel model)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.AbstractServiceHostBuilder`1.Build(ComponentModel model, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WindsorServiceHostFactory`1.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at Program.Main()
```

Any ideas?